# How to restore a dd image to an EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, dd

I have a local dd image myimage.bin, which I want to use to create an AWS EBS volume.

The *only* way I can figure out how to do this is to,

1) Launch an AWS instance

2) Create and attach an EBS volume

3) scp the local myimage.bin to the AWS instance

4) Restore the myimage.bin to the EBS volume from within the instance

Is there no direct way to restore the image directly to an EBS volume or create an EBS volume from a local image via API?

Also the process of scp'ing a GB image is very slow. Even with a high network instance.

Comment: Whatever way you do it, you'll still have to transfer image to Amazon....

Comment: I understand what you mean. Are there any other ways than the one I described?

Comment: Your plan seems fine to me, but let's wait and see if someone has a better idea